# Python : more efficient way to do for this

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and i'm wondering if there is a classy way to do this :

```
if societe_var == 'apple':
    bu_list = bu_list_apple
elif societe_var == 'banana':
    bu_list = bu_list_banana
elif societe_var == 'pear' :
    bu_list = bu_list_pear
else :
    bu_list = bu_list_cherry
```

Best regards,

Kair0

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
bu_list_map = {
    'apple': bu_list_apple,
    'banana': bu_list_banana,
    'pear': bu_list_pear
}

bu_list = bu_list_map.get(societe_var, default=bu_list_cherry)
```

Use the `default` argument to the `.get()` method to handle the fallback case

Answer (score 2):

Put your possible values in a dict and use `.get()` to get one of them (or a default if not found):

```
bu_lists = {
    'apple': bu_list_apple,
    'banana': bu_list_banana,
    'pear': bu_list_pear,
}
bu_list = bu_lists.get(societe_var, bu_list_cherry)
```